# Using Pentaho Kettle, how to load data in output table from CSV file with intermediary step reading in an input table?

Tags: mysql, csv, pentaho, etl, kettle

I have a CSV file which contains data I need to load in a database table using Pentaho ETL Kettle. But before loading them in the table, I need to build each row to be inserted with values I get from the CSV file and values I have to collect from another input table (which needs data from the CSV as parameter to collect wanted info). I'm a bit lost with the steps I have to use to build my transformation. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is this:

- first you read the CSV file with a Text Input step
- then you use a Database Join step where you get additional columns from the table, something like:

  ```
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM input_table
  WHERE common_column = ?
  ```

  with a placeholder ? that will be substituted from a parameter that you have to specify inside this step.
- then you can send yor data to an output step, like a "Table Output".

Something like this:

[image: Read CSV and add columns from a table]

it's not necessarily the most performant solution, it depends on how's your data, or you can use "Database Lookup" step or a "Table Input" step and then a join.

Comment: Thank you @fthiella for the trick. I was trying to do it using a **"Table Input"** step with no success ; the thing is that I don't know how to build the query inside the table input step with parameters coming from the text input step. But it worked fine with database join step. You're my salvator. :) Thank you again.

Comment: @EdouardHINVI if you use a Table Input step you have to read every row (or a filtered set of rows) but you cannot specify any parameter there, you have to use a join rows step later. A database lookup is also a good option but i find the database join easier to understand and to use! You're welcome :)

Comment: The only thing to be aware of here is that `Database Join` does an actual join. If you have multiple rows that match, you'll get multiples in the output unless you specify 1 as "Number of rows to return". If you want only 0 or 1 rows in the output, use a `Database Lookup` or possibly `Stream Lookup` step.